# JQuery language drop-down selector

Tags: jquery

I need an already implemented solution for a JQuery or JavaScript drop-down language selector.
The drop-down should open when the user clicks on it and it should display a list of languages with the country's flag on the left.

I cannot even find an example.

Comment: Please note that this is a question and answer site, not a
code writing service. If you [edit] your question to
describe what you have tried so far and where you are stuck,
then we can try to help with specific problems. You should
also read [ask].

Comment: Please see my answer below. I only needed an example, not the code and I did not try anything at the time, because I did not want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this one without JavaScript only by using CSS.
Fortunately I [found an example](http://picasion.com/) and copied the functionality.

A simple dropdown was not enough, I needed to display the flags of the languages.

Answer (score 2):

Won't any jQuery dropdown plugin work just fine? What you're looking for has nothing to do with languages and everything to do with a dropdown. There are [tons of these](http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+dropdown) just a google away.

Answer (score 1):

Just implement a regular `<select>` box with a `.change()` handler on the combo box.

Are you trying to translate your website on the fly without reloading?

If yes, then Google has it's very own translation widget that you include in your site, it gives you a combo box with language options (without flags) and translates it inline for you to almost any thinkable language.

[Google Translate Tools](http://translate.google.com/translate_tools)