# jQuery language switcher?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

Is there a language switcher plugin for jQuery?
It just should be a dropdown menu with languages and their flags. When you click on a language, it should add a `?lang=xx` to the current URL. I know it's simple to code, but then I have to search flag icons, and I'm lazy :)

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671917/jquery-language-drop-down-selector .

Comment: I can't imagine how a jQuery plugin could help here. The package would have to include hundreds of flag images, just for you to select two or three. (BTW, languages don't have flags!) Wouldn't it be easier just to use normal links (Gasp! No JavaScript!) and get the flags from Wikipedia?

Comment: Flag icons: http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/flags/

Comment: thanks! that's exactly what I searched for. As dropdown menu, I'll now use http://wiki.jqueryui.com/Selectmenu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I now use http://wiki.jqueryui.com/Selectmenu with the flags from @Matt Ball's tip: http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/flags/.
I did it myself because nothing could look better in my "jQuery UI looking" site than another UI widget.

Answer (score 3):

['Polyglot' Language Switcher 2](http://www.ixtendo.com/polyglot-language-switcher-2/)

<strike>[jQuery Slide-Down Language Selector](http://spaceninja.com/2010/02/jquery-slide-down-language-selector/)</strike>

...you'll still have to find your own flags if you want 'em. You're going to have more trouble implementing this that you would a single `<select>` box though.

Personally, my favorite is one found on [Lutron's](http://www.lutron.com) homepage (I might be biased since I worked on the site a bit).

Comment: Link now gives a 404.

Comment: @egr103 - I've added another option since the original was five years out of date.